# ValueError: ('Lengths must match to compare', (120,), (1,))

Tags: python, plotly, dashboard

How to display the data based on the value which inserted in the`dcc.Dropdown(...value=['01/01/2022])`?

Currently, there is no data displayed in the chart based on the value inserted and come out error message as per below:

Error message: ValueError: ('Lengths must match to compare', (120,), (1,))

Does anyone know how to solve it?

```
date_category = list(df['Date'].unique())

app.layout = dbc.Container([
dbc.Row([
   dcc.Dropdown(id='date_drdn', multi=False, value= ['01/01/2022'], 
                 options = [{'label':x, 'value':x} 
                                for x in date_category]
```

Comment: Try using `value='01/01/2022'` (just a string, not a list)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Answer:

Remove the [ ]

example: value= '01/01/2022'

```
date_category = list(df['Date'].unique())

app.layout = dbc.Container([
dbc.Row([
    dcc.Dropdown(id='date_drdn', multi=False, value= '01/01/2022', 
                options = [{'label':x, 'value':x} 
                            for x in date_category]
```